# Error: Unknown user permission: ManageSandboxes

Tags: deployment, permissions, profile, ant, system-admin

When System Administrator profile is deployed through metadata, got the following error.

> **Unknown user permission: ManageSandboxes**

Then I logged into my target organisation and checked `Setup -> Profiles -> System Administrator -> System Permissions`. The `ManageSandboxes` permission was not availble under the `Users` section at the bottom of the page.

But this setting is available in all the other sandboxes and in production instance as well.

All sandboxes and production org have `Summer 20` release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this pressing `Setup -> Company Information -> Match Production Lcienses`.

After pressing this button, `Manage Sandboxes` permission is available now.